# How to replace LSB of a byte with a LSB of another byte

Tags: c#

How to replace LSB of a byte with a LSB of another byte in c#.

Something like this

byte1 - 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

byte2 - 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0

Now i want lsb of byte1 i.e "1" to be replaced by lsb of byte2 i.e "0" .
So my final byte should be like this :

byte3 - 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Comment: using assembler (IL) or what did you mention?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you want something like:

```
byte x = ...;
byte y = ...;

// Only bits 1-7 of x, and only bit 0 of y (counting bit 0 = LSB)
byte z = (byte) ((x & 0xfe) | (y & 1));
```

The cast is necessary because all of the operators are only defined for `int` and larger, so everything gets promoted to `int`.